# Laravel Jetstream Livewire undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I duplicated `<x-slot name="form">` with `<x-slot name="form2">` and inserted variable `$form2` in form-section.blade.php but get an error for undefined `$form2`. I don't know why update-profile-information-form.blade.php didn't send `$form2` HTML. I am using Laravel 8.

> Error: ErrorException Undefined variable: form2 (View:
> \resources\views\vendor\jetstream\components\form-section.blade.php)

**form-section.blade.php**

```
@props(['submit'])

<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => '']) }}>
    <x-jet-section-title>
        <x-slot name="title">{{ $title }}</x-slot>
        <x-slot name="description">{{ $description }}</x-slot>
    </x-jet-section-title>
    <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-6">
        <div class="mt-2 md:mt-0 md:col-span-1">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="{{ $submit }}">
                <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6 shadow {{ isset($actions) ? 'sm:rounded-tl-md sm:rounded-tr-md' : 'sm:rounded-md' }}">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                        {{ $form }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                @if (isset($actions))
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6 shadow sm:rounded-bl-md sm:rounded-br-md">
                        {{ $actions }}
                    </div>
                @endif
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="{{ $submit }}">
                <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6 shadow {{ isset($actions) ? 'sm:rounded-tl-md sm:rounded-tr-md' : 'sm:rounded-md' }}">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                        {{ $form2 }}
                    </div>
                </div>

                @if (isset($actions))
                    <div class="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6 shadow sm:rounded-bl-md sm:rounded-br-md">
                        {{ $actions }}
                    </div>
                @endif
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**update-profile-information-form.blade.php**

```
    <x-jet-form-section submit="updateProfileInformation">
    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ __('Profile Information') }}
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="description">
        {{ __('Update your account\'s profile information and email address.') }}
    </x-slot>
    <x-slot name="form">
        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="name" type="text" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.name" autocomplete="name" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="name" class="mt-2" />
        </div>

        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <x-jet-label for="email" value="{{ __('Email') }}" />
            <x-jet-input id="email" type="email" class="mt-1 block w-full" wire:model.defer="state.email" />
            <x-jet-input-error for="email" class="mt-2" />
        </div>
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="form2">
        <!-- Profile Photo -->
        @if (Laravel\Jetstream\Jetstream::managesProfilePhotos())
        <div x-data="{photoName: null, photoPreview: null}" class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
            <!-- Profile Photo File Input -->
            <input type="file" class="hidden"
                        wire:model="photo"
                        x-ref="photo"
                        x-on:change="
                                photoName = $refs.photo.files[0].name;
                                const reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = (e) => {
                                    photoPreview = e.target.result;
                                };
                                reader.readAsDataURL($refs.photo.files[0]);
                        " />

            <x-jet-label for="photo" value="{{ __('Photo') }}" />

            <!-- Current Profile Photo -->
            <div class="mt-2" x-show="! photoPreview">
                <img src="{{ $this->user->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ $this->user->name }}" class="rounded-full h-20 w-20 object-cover">
            </div>

            <!-- New Profile Photo Preview -->
            <div class="mt-2" x-show="photoPreview">
                <span class="block rounded-full w-20 h-20"
                    x-bind:style="'background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-image: url(\'' + photoPreview + '\');'">
                </span>
            </div>

            <x-jet-secondary-button class="mt-2 mr-2" type="button" x-on:click.prevent="$refs.photo.click()">
                {{ __('Select A New Photo') }}
            </x-jet-secondary-button>

            @if ($this->user->profile_photo_path)
                <x-jet-secondary-button type="button" class="mt-2" wire:click="deleteProfilePhoto">
                    {{ __('Remove Photo') }}
                </x-jet-secondary-button>
            @endif

            <x-jet-input-error for="photo" class="mt-2" />
        </div>
        @endif
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="actions">
        <x-jet-action-message class="mr-3" on="saved">
            {{ __('Saved.') }}
        </x-jet-action-message>

        <x-jet-button wire:loading.attr="disabled" wire:target="photo">
            {{ __('Save') }}
        </x-jet-button>
    </x-slot>
</x-jet-form-section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: you have to bind that $from2 property to the blade, generally from the controller or the component related

Comment: I have <x-slot name="title" .... description ... form, why i cannot add a new one named test and used in that form-section, i searched in all livewire and jetstream and didn't find anything is maked some dynamically

Comment: In debug appear in data, but say is unedefined https://ibb.co/4dXCKh8

Comment: I just found the problem, in form-section.blade.php you have: **@props(['submit', 'test' => ''])** if you don't put default value for that variable test, the variable we'll be see it like undefined...

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem, in form-section.blade.php you have: @props(['submit', 'test' => '']) if you don't put default value for that variable test, the variable we'll be see it like undefined